# Search for 2 strings from multiple pdfs in AWS S3 Bucket which has sub directories without downloading those in local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3, search

Im looking to search for two words in multiple pdfs located in AWS S3 bucket. However, I dont want to download those docs in local machine, instead if the search part could directly run on those pdfs via URL. Point to note that these PDFs are located in multiple sub directories within a bucket ( like year folder, then month folder, then date ).

Answer (score 2):

Amazon S3 does not have a 'Search' capability. It is a "simple storage service".

You would either need to download those documents to some form of compute platform (eg EC2, Lambda, or your own computer) and perform the searches, *or* you could pre-index the documents using a service like [Amazon OpenSearch Service](https://aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/) and then send the query to the search service.

Answer (score 0):

Running a direct scan of PDFs to search for texts in an S3 bucket is HARD:

- Some PDFs contain text that were embedded inside images (They are not readable in text form)
- If you want to download a PDF without saving it, consider using memory-optimized machines and don't store the files in the hard drive of the virtual machines and use in-memory streams.
- In order to get around texts inside images, it would require you to use OCR logic which is also HARD to execute. You'll prolly want to use AWS Textract or Google Vision for OCR. If compliance and security is an issue, you could use  Tesseract.
- If in any case that you have a reliable OCR solution, I would suggest to run a text extraction job after an upload event happens, this will save you tons of money to pay for any OCR service that you'll consume, it will also enable your organization to cache the contents of the pdf in text format in more search-friendly services like AWS [OpenSearch](https://aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/the-elk-stack/what-is-opensearch/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Im only looking for normal pdfs and not for scanned or image pdfs . 

Could anyone suggest me a script in python through which I can search for 2 strings in multiple pdfs located in my local machine all at once? Or if one by one then in for loop

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial which uses Tika (for PDF OCR) and OpenSearch (for search engine) to search the contents of PDF files within an S3 bucket:

```
import boto3
from tika import parser
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch
from config import *
import sys


# opensearch object
os = OpenSearch(opensearch_uri)

s3_file_name="prescription.pdf"
bucket_name="mixpeek-demo"


def download_file():
    """Download the file
    :param str s3_file_name: name of s3 file
    :param str bucket_name: bucket name of where the s3 file is stored
    """

    # s3 boto3 client instantiation
    s3_client = boto3.client(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
        aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
        region_name=region_name
    )

    # open in memory
    with open(s3_file_name, 'wb') as file:
        s3_client.download_fileobj(
            bucket_name,
            s3_file_name,
            file
        )
        print("file downloaded")
        # parse the file
        parsed_pdf_content = parser.from_file(s3_file_name)['content']
        print("file contents extracted")
        # insert parsed pdf content into elasticsearch
        insert_into_search_engine(s3_file_name, parsed_pdf_content)
        print("file contents inserted into search engine")


def insert_into_search_engine(s3_file_name, parsed_pdf_content):
    """Download the file
    :param str s3_file_name: name of s3 file
    :param str parsed_pdf_content: extracted contents of PDF file
    """
    doc = {
        "filename": s3_file_name,
        "parsed_pdf_content": parsed_pdf_content
    }
    # insert
    resp = os.index(
        index = index_name,
        body = doc,
        id = 1,
        refresh = True
    )
    print('\nAdding document:')
    print(resp)


def create_index():
    """Create the index
    """
    index_body = {
        'settings': {
            'index': {
                'number_of_shards': 1
            }
        }
    }
    response = os.indices.create(index_name, body=index_body)
    print('\nCreating index:')
    print(response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    globals()[sys.argv[1]]()
```

full tutorial: https://medium.com/@mixpeek/search-text-from-pdf-files-stored-in-an-s3-bucket-2f10947eebd3

Corresponding github repo: https://github.com/mixpeek/pdf-search-s3